# Get the counts of all first generation nodes neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j

My data structure is very simple. One label called customers with  a one-to-one, one directional relationship to another customer of being referred. What is the correct query to retrieve the counts for each node of all the degrees of referred nodes that resulted from it. 
In other words, if the database consisted 
CustomerA referred CustomerB,
CustomerB referred CustomerC
the resulting table should be:

```
Customer   1st gen referrals   2nd gen referrals
A           1                   1
B           1                   0
C           0                   0
```

Comment: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-length
this may help

Answer (score 0):

You could match on nodes and find the sizes of the desired patterns:

```
MATCH (c:Customer)
RETURN c as Customer, 
  size((c)-[:REFERRED]->()) as firstGenRef, 
  size((c)-[:REFERRED*2]->()) as secondGenRef
```

EDIT

As far as returning the counts of all levels of referrals, that's likely going to be an expensive query, depending on how interconnected your data is.

You can give this a try, and if it takes too long or hangs, you may want to switch to [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), specifically `apoc.path.spanningTree()`, which uses NODE_GLOBAL uniqueness to only retain a single path to each node encountered, that usually performs better.

```
MATCH (c:Customer)-[r:REFERRED*]->(ref)
WITH DISTINCT c, size(r) as gen, ref
WITH c, gen, count(gen) as referrals
ORDER BY gen ASC
RETURN c as  Customer, collect({gen:gen, referrals:referrals}) as referrals
```

This will get you each customer on a row, along with collected maps of the generation and number of referrals at each generation, down to the maximum generation depth per customer.

Comment: Great- thanks! One last refinement. How can we allow for up to n generations with n being the unknown highest degree of any node?

Comment: Added a query you could use for this, though it may be an expensive query.